# How to get value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Alter procedure budgetno_proc
    @wono varchar(max),
    @retvalue varchar(max) output
as
begin
    declare @budno varchar(max)

    if not exists(select * from budgetdet where wono=@wono)
    begin
        set @budno =LEFT(@wono,13)+'-'+RIGHT('0'+CAST((SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(INT,LEFT(@wono,13))),0)+1 from budgetdet WHERE wono=@wono) AS   VARCHAR(20)),1)
    end
    else
    begin
        set @budno=LEFT(@wono,13)+'-'+'1R'+'-'+RIGHT('000'+CAST((SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(budno,18,LEN(budno))))+1 from budgetdet WHERE wono=@wono) AS VARCHAR(20)),3)
    end

    set @retvalue = @budno
end
```

This is my stored procedure with output parameter.

And this is my C# code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gdb"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("budgetno_proc", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wono",Workorder_txt.Text);

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@retvalue", SqlDbType.VarChar,30);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

string budgetnum = (string)cmd.Parameters["@retvalue"].Value;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I can't get that `@retvalue` value from the procedure.

Any changes that I have to make? Please note it.

Thanks

Comment: when parameter is return it shows error value not passed msg.when i set it as output it shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the **ParameterDirection** to **Output** instead of **ReturnValue**

```
  param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string budgetnum = (string)cmd.Parameters["@retvalue"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you need to swap these lines

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
string budgetnum = (string)cmd.Parameters["@retvalue"].Value;
```

Execute first and then try to read the return value

At first glance, if you want to use `ParamDirection.ReturnValue` you need to add the RETURN statement as the last line of your SP, but, looking at [the page about RETURN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) statement you will notice this info about the return expression

> Is the integer value that is returned. Stored procedures can return an
>   integer value to a calling procedure or an application.

So you cannot return a string. This leaves only one option.
Using the `ParamDirection.Output` for the @retvalue parameter instead of the ReturnValue.
Also you have another problem. The size of the parameter cannot be fixed to 30 char if you expect (or declare) an output parameter of VARCHAR(MAX). You need to set the size to -1 on the C# side of your code.
So these lines need to be changed

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@retvalue", SqlDbType.VarChar,-1); //<-Size=-1
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;  // <- Output
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```